# Hop skip zip , Changing multiple Zip folders into real folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, zip

Windows has the built in Zip capability, so I can hop right into a zip like it was a folder.  That does not do a lot of good when you cannot work with the files in the zip.

When downloading lots of zips, be they drivers, or even a simple downloaded media, I can make a folder, and shift the contents of the Zip, over to the new folder, then get rid of the zip. That action is about 5 steps per zip.    I just wish I could remove the dot.zip and the OS would do the extraction , and they are just normal folders then.

In a directory I have a bunch of zips, they are all compatable with windows zipfldr.

```
driver.zip (which can also have internal folders or files or just files)
Driverb.zip
Driverc.zip
Mediafile.zip
Pictures.zip
```

In the same folder can still be other unzipped stuff and loose file items.

In one step Switch ALL of those out of thier Zips, into a Folder by the same name.

```
driver  (regular folder with the zips contents)
Driverb
Driverc
Mediafile
Pictures
```

leaving me to delete the original zip in case something goes wrong. blind overwrite of folders and files (except the zip) is good. Blind misses of files using the same name as the folder is still ok. extraction to a subfolder ok.   . . . An Unpackager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) has a **Extract to "*\"** option in its right-click menu which does exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Thats the one, I did not know they added such an extravagent context menu. I installed it (just now), and  I was able to select Multiples, and knock them all out in way less strokes.  Thanks.